# Change sort order for bundle selected product by name magento

Tags: magento-1.7, collection, product-collection, bundle, bundle-product

I want to sort magento bundle product selected sort order on magento admin.i have changed below code file but nothing happen.i don't know from where it collect collection of product so i can set order. I have set order on this function but nothing changed.

**Mage_Bundle_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Bundle_Option**

```
    public function getOptions()
{
    if (!$this->_options) {
        $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->setStoreFilter($this->getProduct()->getStoreId(),
            $this->getProduct());

        $optionCollection = $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsCollection($this->getProduct());

        $selectionCollection = $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getSelectionsCollection(
            $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($this->getProduct()),
            $this->getProduct()
        );

        $this->_options = $optionCollection->appendSelections($selectionCollection);
        if ($this->getCanReadPrice() === false) {
            foreach ($this->_options as $option) {
                if ($option->getSelections()) {
                    foreach ($option->getSelections() as $selection) {
                        $selection->setCanReadPrice($this->getCanReadPrice());
                        $selection->setCanEditPrice($this->getCanEditPrice());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $this->_options;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class to modify/extend is `Mage_Bundle_Model_Product_Type` then function `getSelectionsCollection.`

```
    public function getSelectionsCollection($optionIds, $product = null)
{
    $keyOptionIds = (is_array($optionIds) ? implode('_', $optionIds) : '');
    $key = $this->_keySelectionsCollection . $keyOptionIds;
    if (!$this->getProduct($product)->hasData($key)) {
        $storeId = $this->getProduct($product)->getStoreId();
        $selectionsCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('bundle/selection_collection')
                ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
                ->addAttributeToSelect('tax_class_id') //used for calculation item taxes in Bundle with Dynamic Price
                ->setFlag('require_stock_items', true)
                ->setFlag('product_children', true)
                //->setPositionOrder() //comment this line
                ->setOrder('name', 'asc') //add this line
                ->addStoreFilter($this->getStoreFilter($product))
                ->setStoreId($storeId)
                ->addFilterByRequiredOptions()
                ->setOptionIdsFilter($optionIds);

        if (!Mage::helper('catalog')->isPriceGlobal() && $storeId) {
            $websiteId = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getWebsiteId();
            $selectionsCollection->joinPrices($websiteId);
        }

        $this->getProduct($product)->setData($key, $selectionsCollection);
    }
    return $this->getProduct($product)->getData($key);
}
```

**Thanks to subroutines**